# decode escape(encodeURIComponent in grails

Tags: grails

I feel dumb for asking this, but I am working with a framework that is posting me data after encoding it via:

```
escape(encodeURIComponent(somedata))
```

I am trying to reverse it on the server side.  I tried `decodeHTML()` and it gets me close, but I need to reverse the escape now.  I tried `decodeJavaScript` as well but it says it DNE.

> No signature of method: java.lang.String.decodeJavaScript() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably my dumbest question was pretty easy to solve.  If something is encoded in js as `escape(encodeURIComponent(somedata))`  the reverse is:

```
params.somedata.decodeHTML().decodeURL()
```

**TMYK**:

The reverse of `escape` is `decodeURL`, the referse of `encodeURIComponent` is `decodeHTML.`